# How to solve these errors multiple views

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

[image: i have multiple table view on a same view how to solve this error]

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if (tableView == method) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *methodcell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(methodcell == nil){
            methodcell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        methodcell.textLabel.text = [methodarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return methodcell;

    }

    else if (tableView == schedule){

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *schedulecell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(schedulecell == nil){
            schedulecell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        schedulecell.textLabel.text = [ScheduleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return schedulecell;
    }


}
```

Comment: This is the poorest description of an error i have ever seen, kindly elaborate more.

Comment: You are getting the error due to not returning a cell. Add `return nil` at the end of your method and the error will go away, however be aware that should none of those if statements pass your app will crash.

Comment: The compiler can see that you are returning cells **only** when either of 2 conditions evaluate to TRUE. Even though you might be sure that one of these conditions will always be true, the compiler does not think that way. It needs you to return a valid cell even if neither of the conditions evaluate to true. Solution: Either change the conditions to `if-  else` instead of `if - else if`, create an else case just to make sure a cell is returned, no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deque cell outside if {} else if {}, configure it depending on tableView and return.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain
                                 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if (tableView == method) {
   //configure cell for method tableView
} else if (tableView == schedule) {
   //configure cell for schedule tableView
}
return cell;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function has the *possibility* of not returning anything. For example, if your `if` and `else if` statements both return `FALSE`, your function won't return anything. This function requires that you return something, so you have a few options (completely dependent on what you want to accomplish):

1. You can add `return nil;` before the last bracket of your function (which will return no cell if no `if` branch was executed)
2. You can change your last `else if` to `else`, so it executes if the `if` returns `FALSE`
3. You can add another `else` branch to your `if` statement

In summary, you need to return ***something*** by the end of that function call.